# How to keep fixed element with dynamic height at the bottom in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a fixed element with dynamic height (*changing when resizing the browser width* ) like the example below :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yuqarh?file=demo.tsx

the element working like  a menu :

- it should be opened in first load (it work)
- hidden when user press hide (*partially work*)
- when click on menu icon open (it work)

in hidden mode I used negative bottom value but this value is fixed while the element height changing if the user resize the browser which causes the element to disappear.

*this element is actually a search component with some inputs but I simplified*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move this element ouside the viewport, you can use transform: translateY(100%); instead of bottom: -125px

```
import * as React from 'react';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import { IconButton, Box, Button, Grid } from '@mui/material';
export default function Demo() {
  const [transform, setTransform] = React.useState('0px');

  return (
    <div style={{ position: 'fixed', bottom: '0px', transform: `translateY(${transform})` }}>
      <div>
        <IconButton onClick={() => setTransform('0')}>
          <MenuIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <Box>
          <Grid container>
            <Box
              sx={{ height: '50px', width: '150px', backgroundColor: 'red' }}
            ></Box>
            <Box
              sx={{ height: '30px', width: '150px', backgroundColor: 'grey' }}
            ></Box>
          </Grid>
          <Button onClick={() => setTransform('calc(100% - 40px)')}>hide</Button>
        </Box>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: when I press hide it completely hide my component I need a partial hide (only the top part which contain the menu icon still appear ) to allow user showing it completely again

Comment: Gotcha, I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
import * as React from 'react';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import { IconButton, Box, Button, Grid } from '@mui/material';
export default function Demo() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);
  return (
    <div style={{ position: 'fixed', bottom: 0 }}>
      <div>
        <IconButton onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
          <MenuIcon />
        </IconButton>
        {open && (
          <Box>
            <Grid container>
              <Box
                sx={{ height: '50px', width: '150px', backgroundColor: 'red' }}
              ></Box>
              <Box
                sx={{ height: '30px', width: '150px', backgroundColor: 'grey' }}
              ></Box>
            </Grid>
          </Box>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I'm not looking to convert menu icon to toggle functionality please read my description of how I need it work (the menu icon will show the component when it hidden only)

Comment: I got you. Just set your bottom somewhere around -100px. For example setShowMenu('-90px'). And it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If we don't do conditional rendering, which I believe would be the ideal solution (for that case, the other answer would be the way to go), the solution to your issue would require simply to extract your burger menu from the div that disappears, as it follows:

```
export default function Demo() {
  const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = React.useState('0px');

  return (
    <>
      <IconButton onClick={() => setShowMenu('0px')}>
        <MenuIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <div style={{ position: 'fixed', bottom: showMenu }}>
        <div>
          <Box>
            <Grid container>
              <Box
                sx={{ height: '50px', width: '150px', backgroundColor: 'red' }}
              ></Box>
              <Box
                sx={{ height: '30px', width: '150px', backgroundColor: 'grey' }}
              ></Box>
            </Grid>
            <Button onClick={() => setShowMenu('-125px')}>hide</Button>
          </Box>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

I would even go as far as suggesting you to have a useToggle custom hook that would have the logic of showing/hiding elements, as it's something fairly common and you most likely will be using it in other components.

Comment: thanks, I tried this scenario but I'm looking if such away to keep the menu icon stick together with my component

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm not completely sure I understand your question then. Anyways, have you tried using relative sizes instead of fixed 125px? For example, a setShowMenu('-100%') should make the whole disappear for every screen height.

Or, you could also use JS Media Queries, in which case I suggest using the react-responsive library, it does an amazing work at that.